# Is it possible to get the y-axis interval in dimple.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, dimple.js

I have drawn a bar graph using dimple.js. I have given the number of y-axis ticks as 5 and now i need to get the interval set between each ticks. Is it possible to get the y-axis interval between each y-axis ticks??

for example : http://jsfiddle.net/keshav_1007/utfnLaz6/  - fiddle

```
var yMax = 1.2;
var svg1 = dimple.newSvg("body", 360, 360);
var dataChart = [{
    "Brand": "Aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SalesVolume": 10
}, {
    "Brand": "Bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SalesVolume": 20
},
                {
    "Brand": "Ccccccccccccccccc",
        "Day": "Mon",
        "SalesVolume": 20
}];
var myChart = new dimple.chart(svg1, dataChart);
myChart.setBounds(120, 10, 200, 200)
var x = myChart.addCategoryAxis("x", "Day");
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
y.ticks = 5;
var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
s.barGap = 0.7;

myChart.draw();
```

I need to get the interval between the y-axis ticks. please let me know how to get this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can get it this way:
First the dimple version you using on fiddle is pretty old use a new version.

```
var y = myChart.addMeasureAxis("y", "SalesVolume");
y.ticks = 5;//setting the ticks
var s = myChart.addSeries("Brand", dimple.plot.bar);
s.barGap = 0.7;
myChart.draw();
console.log(y._tick_step);//get the tickstep
```

Working code [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/utfnLaz6/2/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks cyril it works :) and i will use the latest version here after :)